# Mark a task as a success on callback on intentional failure

Tags: python, airflow

In Airflow 2.3.4, I have a task I am intentionally failing and when it fails I want to mark it as a success
in the callback but the below does not work.,

```
def intentional_failure():
     raise AirflowException("this is a dummy failure")

def handle_failure(context):
     context['task_instance'].state = State.SUCCESS

dummy_failure = PythonOperator(task_id="intentional_failure", python_callable=intentional_failure, on_failure_callback=handle_failure)
```

How would I programatically mark a task as success on an intentional failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it is a method call not an attribute. So we need to set `context['ti'].set_state(State.SUCCESS)` in the `on_failure_callback`.